# Iterating a list of lists and modifying values backwards

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list of lists, like so.

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 7], [9, 5, 6]]
```

I want to subtract the first element of each sublist by the first element of the previous sublist, and afterwards, I also want to set the first element of the first sublist to zero. Yielding

```
[[0, 2, 3], [3, 2, 7], [5, 5, 6]]
```

I have tried writing a function for this a few times and i can't figure out how i would iterate through - because if I want the subtraction to be with all of the original values, for example, after I subtract 4 by 1 and get 3 for the first element of the second list, i would still want to subtract 9 (first element of the third list) by 4 (original value of the second list), not 3.

At first it seems like i would need to iterate through the list backwards but i have no idea how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got the question right, you want to only modify the first element of the sub lists, right? You could do something like this-

```
li = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 7], [9, 5, 6]]
for i in range(2, 0, -1):
    li[i][0] = li[i][0] - li[i-1][0]
li[0][0] = 0
```

Starting from the back, you subtract from it the first element of the previous sublist and finally set the first element of the first list 0. Of course you can use len(li)-1 instead of just using 2 in case its for a different array.

Comment: for i in range(2, 1, -1):
should be
for i in range(2, 0, -1):

Comment: Yes, typo. Thank you for pointing that out. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old zip-the-list-with-itself trick:

```
lists= [[1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 7], [9, 5, 6]]

i= reversed(lists) # iterate backwards
next(i) # drop the first (last) list
j= reversed(lists) # create another reversed iterator, but don't drop the 1st list
for list1, list2 in zip(i, j): # zip the two iterators
    list2[0]-= list1[0]
lists[0][0]= 0 # set first value to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 7], [9, 5, 6] ]
# print(lst)
t = [ lst[0] ]

for i in range( 1, len(lst) ):
    x = [ lst[i][0] - lst[i-1][0] ]
    x.extend( lst[i][1:] )
    t.append( x )

t[0][0] = 0
print(t)
```

Result will be:

`[[0, 2, 3], [3, 2, 7], [5, 5, 6]]`